# Vault ingress - how to point to vault-ui service when HA is enabled

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, hashicorp-vault, vault

Having a simple UI access issue:

I know (from documentation)  that when `ha` is enabled, then ingress points to `vault-active` service automatically.  I need HA enabled as I am using consul as a backend for vault.

But, how can I use ingress (even a separate new one) to point to `vault-ui` service so that I can access it on myvault.mywebsite.com/ui ?

I tried many things but didn't get any success.
Please help.

Vault chart version: vault-0.21.0
Vault App version: 1.11.2
Kubectl version:

- Client:    Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.10"
- Server: Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.10"

Here's my values.yaml and ingress yaml file:

```
> server:
>   ha:
>     enabled: true
>     replicas: 3
>     config: |
>       ui = true
>       storage "consul" {
>         path = "vault"
>         address = "myconsul.mywebsite.com:8500"
>       }
>   ingress:
>     enabled: true
> ui:
>   enabled: true
```

This creates default nginx ingress rule that points to `vault-active` service.

Now, if I create following separate ingress object, the nginx rejects it as the host name is same and if I change the hostname, nginx accepts it but I get `502: Bad Gateway` error when I visit myvault.mywebsite.com

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: vault-ingress
  namespace: vault
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: myvault.mywebsite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: vault-ui
          servicePort: 80
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration file looks for Vault on port 80. That would require Vault to run as `root`, not a good idea.

Make sure `servicePort` matches your Vault port, the default is `8200`. You also need to [set `tls_disable: true`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/configuration/listener/tcp#tls_disable) in your chart.

Should look something like this:

```
server:
  ha:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 3
    config: |
      ui = true
      ### Add this stanza to have
      ### Vault listen on HTTP on port 8200
      listener "tcp" {
        address = "[::]:8200"
         tls_disable =  true
      }
      ### 
      storage "consul" {
        path = "vault"
        address = "myconsul.mywebsite.com:8500"
      }
  ingress:
    enabled: true
ui:
  enabled: true
```

Comment: I tried your solution too but still no luck. :(

Here's my values.yaml:
``` server:
  ha:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 3
    config: |
      ui = true
      ### Add this stanza to have
      ### Vault listen on HTTP on port 8200
      listener "tcp" {
        address = "[::]:8200"
         tls_disable =  true
      }
      ###
      storage "consul" {
        path = "vault"
        address = "myconsul.mywebsite.com:8500"
      }
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    hosts:
      - host: my-vault.mywebsite.com
    ingressClassName: nginx
ui:
  enabled: true
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure what's wrong but I am not getting any option to format my code while posting comment here. So, apologies for the unformated vaules.yaml posted above in reply.

Comment: Also, please see what else I have tried from my discussion here:  https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/17002

I would really appreciate any help on this.